# HttpHandler for a specific port

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application built on ASP.NET MVC framework which requires a service payment module. For the given service payment provider, I have to create a module that listens to a specific port (different from 80) at a specific url. What is the best way to achieve this? Should I create a separate Http Server application which would listen to those connections? Is there a way to create an HttpHandler in the context of the main web application that would process the request for a given port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of two options do this:

1. As you said create a new web application bound to listen to requests on the specified url & port.
2. Bind the website to listen to both port 80 and this other URL. Then when you write your handler you could look at the `Request` object to determine the URL

Personally I prefer the first choice.

Answer (score 2):

In your `PostMapRequestHandler event` check the port.  If it's the port you want to use then set the `HttpHandler` to be your custom handler, otherwise don't do anything.

For example,

```
        EventHandler WireThisToHttpApplicationPostMapRequestHandler = (sender, args) =>
              {
                  var httpApplication = (HttpApplication) sender;
                  var portString =httpApplication.Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_PORT"];
                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(portString))
                  {
                      var port = int.Parse(portString);
                      if (port == 8675309)
                      {
                          httpApplication.Context.Handler = new TommyTutoneHttpHandler();
                      }
                  }
              };
```